# Springbatch processing

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I would like to build a batch with 3 steps. I want to configur this steps like 
If there are 100 records when step1 read and process and write a chunk of 10 step02 then step03 starts and ends and then it goes back to step1 again and read the next chunk.
Is this possible in Spring batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is possible.
You have to think that in step2 you have to "read" again the last 10 items read by step1 because in steps reader is mandatory and this items should be stored in execution-context so best pratice is to store only keys (if you are working with DB or others solution that involves a query driver solution) to minimize data usage because execution-context is stored in SB metadata tables.
The same for step 3.
After step 3 with a `JobExecutionDecider` move back to step1 if you have more elements to process or move to end of job.

This can be a possible solution but - IMHO - looks like a perversion compared to how we are used to design job flow with SB; are you sure you can't do the same job with a single step,3 processors and few listeneres rethinking the job flow?